# Heat losses of warm fluid in a cold pipe

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, heat-transfer

I'm looking for a way to calculate/estimate heat loss in a fluid flowing trough a pipe for a length (l) and travel time for the fluid (t). The flow is intermittent and the initial pipe temperature (Tpi = Tambient) at steady state is lower (different) than the initial fluid temperature (Tfi), i.e. Tfi>Tpi or possibly Tfi<Tpi. The flow is mostly turbulent and the pipe is not filled, flowrate Q is variable. The time t is typically lower than 60 seconds. As I said, flow is intermittent and may last for 5 seconds up to say 1800 seconds, and flow events are separated by 60-3600 seconds of no flow.
Additional info: heat capacity of the fluid is 4.186 J/g/K, pipe material 0.9 J/g/K. Pipe diameter is 75 mm.

What would be a robust way to calculate temperature change of the fluid in the pipe?

Comment: Teaching you an advanced heat transfer course is beyond the scope of this SE.  We would expect you to have a solution you have tried.  Directly here, you need heat transfer rates to the pipe, from the pipe to environment, and the heating of the pipe, which I believe is modeled by a differential equation for each of those since the temperature isn't steady-state, which is basically beyond the undergrad heat transfer course.

Comment: Of course, I was more looking for pointers as where to start looking.

Comment: beginning and advanced heat transfer textbooks

Comment: I would recommend starting with the steady state heat transfer. Transient version may be possible to solve analytically, but probably with many simplifications. Still, that may be good enough...

Comment: I suggest a simple thermal resistance model. TempIncrease= (Other1Temp-ThisTemp)*R1+(Other2-ThisTemp)*R2... Etc.  You have the fluid in a section of pipe, the pipe itself, the inlet, the outlet, maybe some environment(s) around the pipe. The more elements and sections you make, the more accurate you should get.